# Why my parameter shows me an error Failed to evaluate the FilterValues of the DataSet?

Tags: reporting-services, report

I want to get available values from query in my ssrs report parameter.
I set Get values from a query

```
DataSet : name of my dataset#

Value field: my field

Label field : my field
```

To get an idea i will show you what i mean:
[image]

[image]

[image]

For expected results :  I want to use my parameter as multie value parameter..

Comment: alright for beginning remove filter and just preview report with your parameter,
When you do not you should be able to preview the report without any error.
If possible try to add screenshot of Previewed report with your parameter's and it's values

Comment: I did this , but when i removed my filter .. i received all values with those,which i didn't mark....

Comment: I answered your question below. Did you tried my solution. It shall work

Comment: Same error.Failed to evaluate the FilterValues !

Comment: can u add new screenshot from your filter expression not sure where u r going wrong

Comment: Here is : https://imgur.com/a/CG82zLn

Answer (score 1):

Your expression should be something like this and you need to add this expression by pressing fx next to value rather than directly adding it.

```
=IIF(Parameters!RootPoint.Value(0)="",Fields!C_RootPoint.Value,Parameters!RootPoint.Value(0))
```

also if you are trying to check if your first parameter value is null then you should try like below

```
=IIF(Isnothing(Parameters!RootPoint.Value(0)),Fields!C_RootPoint.Value,Parameters!RootPoint.Value(0))
```